# Reload ajax data after react-router change query or hash

Tags: ajax, reactjs, react-router

**I have a component Careers.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import axios from 'axios'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import qs from 'query-string';

import Filters from './Filters'

const CareersList = ({ location, careers }) => {
  return (
    <div className="careers_listing">
      {location.search}
      { careers.map((career) =>
        <div key={career.id}>
          {career.title}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

class Careers extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    this.getCareers();
  }

  getCareers() {
    axios.get(this.props.url)
      .then(res => {
        const careers = res.data.careers;
        this.setState({ careers });
      });
  }

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      careers: []
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="rct">
          <Filters filters={this.props.filters} path={this.props.path} />
          <div className="rct_listing">
            <Route path={decodeURIComponent(this.props.path)} render={props => (
              <CareersList careers={this.state.careers} {...props} />
            )}/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default Careers
```

I want to filter careers list by query or hash params, like: /careers?type=public. I can filter by `.find()`, but I want to reload ajax data with special params and rerender list.

Main problem: I can't access to `getCareers()` from CareersList. How I can reload Career state from CareersList component?

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the method as a prop to CareersList for example:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import axios from 'axios'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import qs from 'query-string';

import Filters from './Filters'

const CareersList = ({ location, careers }) => {
  // You can call `this.props.getCareers()` here
  return (
    <div className="careers_listing">
      {location.search}
      { careers.map((career) =>
        <div key={career.id}>
          {career.title}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

class Careers extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    this.getCareers();
  }

  getCareers() {
    axios.get(this.props.url)
      .then(res => {
        const careers = res.data.careers;
        this.setState({ careers });
      });
  }

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      careers: []
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="rct">
          <Filters filters={this.props.filters} path={this.props.path} />
          <div className="rct_listing">
            <Route path={decodeURIComponent(this.props.path)} render={props => (
              <CareersList getCareers={this.getCareers} careers={this.state.careers} {...props} />
            )}/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default Careers
```

Comment: Yeah, I think about it.. is it "correct" (best practice) way to solve this task?

Comment: In this situation I can't access to this.props from Careers component. `axios.get(this.props.url)` — undefined url

Comment: If `this` is undefined, you just have to bind it to the function like, for example; `<CareersList getCareers={this.getCareers.bind(this)} />`